# Libraries and tools for application level DB encryption

Tags: java, database, encryption, jdbc, integrity

Suppose I am making an app that runs on cloud and also uses a cloud DB (possibly a different cloud than the app). For security, I am looking at app level encryption, since I cannot really rely on the cloud provider's promise to "keep the data secure", and I cannot also trust any DB-level encryption happening on a server at a remote unknown location. Hence I am looking at app level encryption.

I had a look at several vendors (such as [Vormetric](http://www.vormetric.com/sites/default/files/data-sheet-Vormetric-data-security-platform.pdf), [ProtectApp](http://www.safenet-inc.com/data-encryption/application-security/protectapp-application-protection/), [Thales](https://www.thales-esecurity.com/solutions/by-technology-focus/application-level-encryption)) but they all seem to have a complex solution that requires licensing and probably custom hardware or servers, not something suited for small businesses.

I am looking for tools (preferably opensource) that allow a user to design from scratch, an app level encryption mechanism without having a deep knowledge of crypto. Something like a layer on top of JDBC or an ORM.

(this is primarily Java based)

I am able to do my own key management fine so not looking at those heavy solutions. I just need a library that lets me apply all the various encryption features and allow me to query the DB without losing the functionality. I can select the type of encryption based on the type of queries I need to make on certain columns. Ideally the library should be a wrapper on the DB that also does the querying for me.

It will also be fine to know that something like this does not exist (or has usability issues), so I can go ahead and make my own library.

Comment: For close votes, can you comment why it is not appropriate?

Comment: @Just12 Requests for recommendations for offsite resources like libraries are off topic on stackoverflow

Comment: Ok, is there any better place where I can ask this question. Seems to be an important question.

Comment: There is http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Another option is to rephrase your question so you are not asking for a library (although given your question, that might then be considered too broad).

Answer (score 1):

A very good address is the [Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_Security_Frameworks). 
For your purpose I would suggest a deeper look at:

- [Antisami](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project) (Input Validation + Output encoding)
- [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) (Almost everything)
- [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) (very good cryptography lib)
- [ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API)  (Almost eveything)